# mail sending with attachement in android application

Tags: android

Thanks in advance,
HOw to send mail in android application with some file attached in attachement..
and I want to send this mail automatically not use any another mail screen or navigation..

Thanks again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me, but i think email a png file from your device may help you...

Here is the code

> private static int EMAIL_SUCCESS = 10;//This is the response code.
>
> ```
> File pngFile = new File(Path to your image file);
>               Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(pngFile);
>
>               String tag = "Your Text here";
>
>               Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>               intent.setType("image/png");
>
>               intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
>                       "Email Subject Here");
>
>               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tag);
>               intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
>     startActivityForResult(intent, EMAIL_SUCCESS);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should have configured some service which can send the mails.

2nd, you need to write an app to interact with the service which can receive this information and send the mails.

So, please explain completely about your requirement.

Comment: I want to send a mail with some file attach there, when I will press a button then mail is send automatically, not display any window..

Comment: @ManojKumar, I understand, i their a SMTP server available to you? If not would like to use the Google's SMTP service? I you are using googles SMTP service, you need to see how you can authenticate yourself to the server and also, need to know what all parameters are mandetory for the mail sending.

Answer (score 1):

The code below may help you:

```
Button mail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Lockbttn);

mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          i.setType("text/plain") ; 
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"rajubarad@yahoo.com"});
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject Title");
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Message body description");
          i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mysdfile.txt")));
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Select email application"));
    }
});
```

And if your want to send mail without any immediate window.

```
     // set startActivity with intent only
        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
public class SendAttachment{
                    public static void main(String [] args){ 
             //to address
                    String to="abc@abc.com";//change accordingly
                    //from address
                    final String user="efg@efg.com";//change accordingly
                    final String password="password";//change accordingly 
                     MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
                   mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
                  mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
                  mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
                  mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
                  mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
                  CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
                  //1) get the session object   
                  Properties properties = System.getProperties();
                  properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
                  properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
                   }
                  });

                  //2) compose message   
                  try{ 
                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
                    message.setSubject("Hii"); 
                    //3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message content    
                    BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
                    messageBodyPart1.setText("How is This"); 
                    //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object    
                    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
                //Location of file to be attached
                    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/R2832.zip";//change accordingly
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                    messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    messageBodyPart2.setFileName("Hello"); 
                    //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object    
                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2); 
                    //6) set the multiplart object to the message object
                    message.setContent(multipart ); 
                    //7) send message 
                    Transport.send(message); 
                   System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT....");
                   }catch (MessagingException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
                  }
                }
```

Comment: ADD THE JAR FILES
activation.jar
additionnal.jar
javax.mail.jar